# ASP.net LINQ on DataView to use Like query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, dataview

I want to filter a `DataView` but `DV.Rowfilter` is taking too much time .

```
dv.RowFilter = "ProductName like '%" + searchtxt + "%'";
```

So I decided to use the LINQ but how to implement above **like** query in LINQ ?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not more efficient in general, but it can increase readability and maintainability.

So you can try `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
var query = from row in dv.Table.AsEnumerable()
            let productName = row.Field<string>("ProductName")
            where productName.Contains(searchtxt)
            select row;
DataTable tbl = query.CopyToDataTable(); // use this as DataSource or use tbl.DefaultView
```

Here the same with method syntax:

```
var query = dv.Table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("ProductName").Contains(searchtxt));
```

[MSDN: Creating a DataView Object with LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669080(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

> i have tried your second solution, but now its throwing the exception
>   "The source contains no DataRows." and actually the `DataTable` which i
>   make as DataTable.AsEnumerable() , it has the rows in it

The table contains rows but the filter skips all of them.

You could use `if(query.Any()){...}` to check if there are rows:

```
DataTable tbl = dv.Table.Clone(); // creates an empty table with the same columns
if(query.Any())
    tbl = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: @Jumbo: you're welcome. But does the answer help, it it more efficient? If not, maybe you have too many rows and you should reduce the rows you load into memory(f.e. sql-paging). If yes, consider to accept the answer.

Comment: THanx for ur reply ,but firs solution is not working ,its giving exception as "Can not create DataView after using projection".

and I have tried second also but it's not getting any records.

Would u please tell me another solution ?

Comment: @Jumbo: then try to use a `DataTable` instead. I've edited my answer. If you need the `DataView` you can use `tbl.DefaultView`.

Comment: i have tried ur second solution,but now its throwing the exception "The source contains no DataRows." and actually the datatable which i make as Datable.AsEnumerable() , it has the rows in it.
Please suggest something else...

Comment: @Jumbo: the table contains rows but no the query, so the filter filters iout all rows. You could use `if(Query.Any()){...}` to check if there are rows.